# Implementing Publish / Subscribe and / or a Message Bus with Xamarin & Unity3D clients

Tags: web-apps, mobile, game-development, message-broker

As the title says, I have a requirement where I need to design a message bus with multiple types of client consumers - in this instance, Unity3D, Xamarin and web clients (AJAX). Essentially I need to push notifications out to all clients when various events occur.

I'm using dot net core for all server-side code, which is being hosted in linux-based docker containers. There is a REST API for transactional / CRUD events.

I've used NServiceBus, SignalR and MSMQ quite a bit in the past, and looked into them all for this scenario - but they're either not supported by dot net core, or their client packages aren't supported by Mono. Yet to put a proof of concept together for MassTransit or RabbitMQ - used them both in the past, but only as a consumer from a dot net framework app - they were already implemented before I came along.

Looking for possible solutions and / or suggested frameworks that would allow me to subscribe to events by remote clients and push. Open to any suggestions as long as they're compatible with dot net core on the server side, then Mono and JS on the client side.